# Azure Stack System Requirements for each server or whole setup?

Tags: azure

Azure Stack is coming out soon and I am planning a server farm that can run it. Do the [system specs provided by Microsoft](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloud/2015/12/21/microsoft-azure-stack-hardware-requirements/) apply to each server within the farm or all of the servers together?

For example:

- the requirement is 12 physical cores. Can I have three servers with 4 cores each?
- the requirement is 96 GB of RAM. Can I have three servers with 32GB of RAM each?
- the requirement is 1 OS disk with 200GB available for system partition. Can I have 1 OS disk on each machine of 500GB?
- the requirement is 4 disks, each with a minimum capacity of 140GB. Can I have three servers with a single 500GB data disk?

Anybody tried running on lesser hardware?

Comment: Fairly certain that's one machine. I tried to install it on my machine (8 core/32GB) a while back and the installer laughed at me till I nearly cried.

Comment: Dang, I figured it would be a distributed runtime. Stitch together a bunch of commodity hardware and such.